# Exporting modules to be importable like Grid and Grid.Item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to use two components like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Item>A</Grid.Item>
  <Grid.Item>B</Grid.Item>
</Grid>
```

How do I export these components to be importable like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how `Grid` is exported from `react-semantic-ui` package

```
const myComponent = () => // code
const mySubComponent1 = () => // code
const mySubComponent2 = () => // code

myComponent.mySubComponent1 = mySubComponent1;
myComponent.mySubComponent2 = mySubComponent2;

export default myComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export them like:

```
export const Item () => // render Item code

class Grid extends Component {
  // Component code...
}
Grid.Item = Item
export default Grid;
```

Comment: Hi mate, same answer, but arrow function after default export is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to export an object with properties with components.

```
import React from 'react';

export default {
  Grid: function Grid() { return <div>grid</div>},
  Item: function Item() { return <li>I am item</li> },
};

// usage
import Components from '..';

<Components.Grid>
  <Components.Item />
</Components.Grid>
```

Comment: Hi mate, this will not work with IE `import Grid from 'my-package'`take a look to other answers.